# Unable to open graphical view of an element in clearcase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am unable to open graphical view of an element in ClearCase.

While doing: `clearcase lsvtree -g`

I get:

> xclearcase : warning: could not load font 'GB2312.1980-0'

Answer (score 0):

Check first (if `xclearcase` means an old ClearCase 7.x on Linux or Solaris) if this is `LANG` issue: see [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21257223).

> It was determined that the `LANG` variable was unset on UNIX® or Linux® and caused the core to occur when the remote display attempted to process `xclearcase` data.
>
> This could also be caused by an incorrect LANG variable setting.
>
> This may also occur on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6 when the X11 display is local to the RHEL6 system.
>
> If the `LANG` environment is set, this issue can be resolved on RHEL5 by changing the `LANG` environment variable setting from the default `en_US.UTF-8` to `en_US`.

Workarounds:

> - Option 1:
>     You may be able to resolve the issue by creating the following link on the server:

```
    /usr/lib/X11/nls/XhpV3/C -> /usr/lib/X11/nls/XhpV3/iso88591
```

> - Option 2:
>     You can try to change your `Exceed` setting from "`PseudoColor`" to "`Auto Select`" in order to connect.
> - Option 3:
>     Under BlueZoneX server software, the fix was to tell it to use the Microsoft fonts as well as the ones from BlueZone.

Comment: This is the labmachine(Virtual machine) we have configured

Comment: What version of ClearCase have you installed on it? What is the output of cat /etc/os-release when done in this VM?

Comment: This is the labmachine(Virtual machine) we have configured on users request with Rhel  7.2 (Mapio). Earlier it asks for libMrm.so.3 after installing that pack we got this error(xclearcase : warning: could not load font 'GB2312.1980-0' , KSC5601.1987-0 , JISX0208.1983-0).

But in our main server we had RHEL 6.5 its working fine.Clearcase version is 8.0.13 for both m/c's

Comment: shoots error
/usr/lib/X11/nls/XhpV3/C -> /usr/lib/X11/nls/XhpV3/iso88591
-bash: /usr/lib/X11/nls/XhpV3/iso88591: No such file or directory

Comment: where can i change exceed settings??
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21257223

i have seen this link  couple of days back which consists the options u suggested but where i have to change?

Comment: If you are using Windows-based X server software (Exceed, Cygwin-X, etc.) you're using an explicitly unsupported configuration. If you can replicate it via VNC to the ClearCase host, opening a PMR with IBM may be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment gets folded in, I'll enter it as an "answer."

ClearCase explicitly does not support X sessions where the X server is a Windows host. This isn't to say it doesn't mostly work, but when it breaks down, the answer is usually "You're on your own."

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=219&context=SSCBN78&q1=linux&uid=swg21128395&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en

A local CTE, or a VNC session are better options for accessing the Unix-based resources from windows without installing the full CC client.

Eclipse over X-forwarding may be acutely painful, depending on the location of the CC host and the X server. I tried it over a VPN once, JUST once. VNC was MUCH better.